# Handling file in WP-- oplock broken

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to, in some instances, read from, and in others, write to a file in Windows Phone 8.1. I am using the following code to read it:

```
var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
try
{
    var connectionsFile = await folder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("connections");
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(connectionsFile, Encoding.Unicode))
    {
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            String con = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
            String[] props = con.Split('\t');
            Connection newConnection = new Connection() { Name = props[0], Url = props[1] };
            ConnectionsCollection.Add(newCollection);
        }
        await connectionsFile.FlushAsync();
        connectionsFile.Dispose();
     }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //handle exception
}
```

My problem is that it unfailingly hits the catch with an inner exception of "The handle with which this oplock was associated has been closed. The oplock is now broken." (I get the same error when trying to write to it.)  I can't figure out what the problem is, especially since I am successfully using the same code to read the same file in two other places.

Comment: I think you needs to remove the `await connectionsFile.FlushAsync();` line because you're using the file for reading. Also remove the `connectionsFile.Dispose();` and use the `using(...)` in connectionsFile assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you needs to remove the `await connectionsFile.FlushAsync();` line because you're using the file for reading. Also remove the `connectionsFile.Dispose();` and use the `using(...)` in connectionsFile assignment.

```
var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
try
{
    using (var connectionsFile = await folder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("connections"))
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(connectionsFile, Encoding.Unicode))
    {
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            String con = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
            String[] props = con.Split('\t');
            Connection newConnection = new Connection() {Name = props[0], Url = props[1]};
            ConnectionsCollection.Add(newCollection);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //handle exception
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: @Shawn maybe the error is because of concurrence threading. Probably you're trying to access the same file at same time.

Comment: I have it reading from the file only once and it still gives the error.